# 404 GET / When index.html is available

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

I'm trying to write a simple static site in Crystal using Kemal.

Going by [this page](http://kemalcr.com/docs/static_files/), I should be fine, but I get a 404 when I try to load the site.

My program looks like this (you can see all the code I commented out trying to track the issue down)

```
#require "./LiedThisWeek/*"
require "kemal"

#module LiedThisWeek
  # TODO Put your code here
#end

#finder = LieFinder.new
#handler = HyperTextHandler.new finder
#indexPath = "public/index.html"
#
#spawn do
#   loop do
#       finder.refresh
#       File.write indexPath, handler.getDoc
#       sleep 60.second
#   end
#end

Kemal.run
```

This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── LiedThisWeek
├── README.md
├── lib (removed for brevity)
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── fireworks.jpg
│   │   └── sad.jpg
│   └── index.html
├── shard.lock
├── shard.yml
├── spec
│   ├── LiedThisWeek_spec.cr
│   └── spec_helper.cr
└── src
    ├── LiedThisWeek
    │   ├── HyperTextHandler.cr
    │   ├── Lie.cr
    │   ├── LieFinder.cr
    │   └── version.cr
    └── LiedThisWeek.cr

32 directories, 112 files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kemal author here.

Kemal doesn't serve `index.html` as `/` by default. However you can achieve that with a `redirect`

```
get "/" do |env|
  env.redirect "index.html"
end
```

Comment: I was literally seconds away from posting an issue about this. Thank you!